# Ruby split does not working on string?

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to split a string to capitalize each word.

Code:

```
def titleize(a)
little_words = %w(a an the)
#a = %w(a quick brown fox jumps) --> works if an array is specifically used.
a.split(" ")
a.each do |i|
    if !little_words.include? "#{i}"
    i.capitalize!
    end
end
g = a.join(" ")
return g
end

print titleize("a quick brown fox jump")
```

Error:

```
  `titleize': undefined method `each' for "a quick brown fox jump":String (NoMethodError)
```

However, I am running into this error. From what I understand, the error is saying that my variable 'a' is a string which does not contain the method 'each'. I have already applied 'split(" ")' to convert the string to an array. Why does it not work?

Comment: You use the split but you don't store the resulting array anywhere. "a" is still a string which doesn't have an "each" method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are ignoring what the method returns

```
a = a.split(" ")
```

And `" "` is the default for split so you can write simply

```
a = a.split
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand the ruby has certain methods such as "i.to_s" which converts an integer to string without having to deal with a return. Is there any equivalent for split?

Comment: `to_s` returns a string but don't modify the object on which is called. It's the same. There are some methods that modify object in-place but they return the same "type", in this case split is called on a string and returns an array, is not possible

Comment: @axiac `!` is only a convention, there are several methods without `!` that modify the receiver. I think more important is the fact that an object can't change its identity. A string can modify itself, i.e. its characters, but it can't turn itself into an array or an integer. A string will always be a string.